# Webpack watchOptions.ignored – exclude certain directories from being ignored

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, webpack, webpack-dev-server

For [webpack's watch feature](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/), [`watchOptions.ignored`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptionsignored) allows me to specify [anymatch](https://github.com/micromatch/anymatch) patterns to ignore, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: ['files/**/*.js', 'node_modules']
  }
};
```

Is it possible to use an anymatch or regex pattern to also specify subfolders of `node_modules` to **not** ignore?

In this situation, I need to ignore everything in `node_modules` **except for** all subfolders of `node_modules` that start with "`abc-`".

Comment: Seems `ignored` option accept `globs` not `regexps`

Comment: @Maxim - According to the documentation (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptionsignored), it accepts RegExp and anymatch parameters.

Comment: Any resolution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to exclude all folder that does not have `/src/`. I tried negative on glob pattern, which did not work.

**watchOptions.ignored**

`RegExp` `string` `[string]`

The document says it supports `string` and `[string]` where string can be glob patterns.

> When using glob patterns, we convert them to regular expressions with glob-to-regexp

Since they use [glob-to-regexp](https://github.com/fitzgen/glob-to-regexp) internally, I think the negative match does not work as expected https://github.com/fitzgen/glob-to-regexp/issues/15

---

Since the document says we can use `RegExp` too. **I tried following two, and both worked!**

```
watchOptions: {
    ignored: new RegExp('.*^((?!(/src/)).)*$'),
},
```

and

```
watchOptions: {
    ignored: '.*^((?!(/src/)).)*$',
},
```

I don't think it support array having `RegExp` *(for multiple case we can use regex or).*

If you use regex, you will be able achieve the case mentioned in this question.

Reference:

- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptionsignored